# How can I emit periodic results over an iteration?

Tags: scala

I might have something like this:

```
val found = source.toCharArray.foreach{ c =>
  // Process char c
  // Sometimes (e.g. on newline) I want to emit a result to be
  // captured in 'found'.  There may be 0 or more captured results.
}
```

This shows my intent.  I want to iterate over some collection of things.  Whenever the need arrises I want to "emit" a result to be captured in found.  It's not a direct 1-for-1 like map.  collect() is a "pull", applying a partial function over the collection.  I want a "push" behavior, where I visit everything but push out something when needed.

Is there a pattern or collection method I'm missing that does this?

Comment: Are you looking for `filter`?

Comment: Don't think so.  In my case I'm iterating over characters in a string, processing each one, and on certain conditions "emit" a processed result. Not clear how filter would work for that.

Comment: Maybe `flatMap` then, which allows you to "emit" none, one or multiple values.

Comment: Or just use `collect`. The only difference between "push" and "pull" appears to be the evaluation strategy, not the result.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you have a `Collection[Thing]`, and you want to obtain a new `Collection[Event]` by emitting a `Collection[Event]` for each `Thing`. That is, you want a function

```
(Collection[Thing], Thing => Collection[Event]) => Collection[Event]
```

That's exactly what `flatMap` does.

---

You can write it down with nested `for`s where the second generator defines what "events" have to be "emitted" for each input from the source. For example:

```
val input = "a2ba4b"

val result = (for {
  c <- input
  emitted <- {
    if (c == 'a') List('A')
    else if (c.isDigit) List.fill(c.toString.toInt)('|')
    else Nil
  }
} yield emitted).mkString

println(result)
```

prints

```
 A||A||||
```

because each `'a'` emits an `'A'`, each digit emits the right amount of tally marks, and all other symbols are ignored.

---

There are several other ways to express the same thing, for example, the above expression could also be rewritten with an explicit `flatMap` and with a pattern match instead of `if-else`:

```
println(input.flatMap{
  case 'a' => "A"
  case d if d.isDigit => "|" * (d.toString.toInt)
  case _ => ""
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a way to build a `Stream` for your condition. `Streams` are lazy and are computed only when required.

```
val sourceString = "sdfdsdsfssd\ndfgdfgd\nsdfsfsggdfg\ndsgsfgdfgdfg\nsdfsffdg\nersdff\n"

val sourceStream = sourceString.toCharArray.toStream

def foundStreamCreator( source: Stream[Char], emmitBoundaryFunction: Char => Boolean): Stream[String] = {
  def loop(sourceStream: Stream[Char], collector: List[Char]): Stream[String] =
    sourceStream.isEmpty match {
      case true => collector.mkString.reverse #:: Stream.empty[String]
      case false => {
        val char = sourceStream.head
        emmitBoundaryFunction(char) match {
          case true =>
            collector.mkString.reverse #:: loop(sourceStream.tail, List.empty[Char])
          case false =>
            loop(sourceStream.tail, char :: collector)
        }
      }
    }

  loop(source, List.empty[Char])
}

val foundStream = foundStreamCreator(sourceStream, c => c == '\n')

val foundIterator = foundStream.toIterator

foundIterator.next()
// res0: String = sdfdsdsfssd
foundIterator.next()
// res1: String = dfgdfgd
foundIterator.next()
// res2: String = sdfsfsggdfg
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `foldLeft` to me:

```
val found = ((List.empty[String], "") /: source.toCharArray) {case ((agg, tmp), char) =>
  if (char == '\n') (tmp :: agg, "") // <- emit
  else (agg, tmp + char)
}._1
```

Where you keep collecting items in a temporary location and then emit it when you run into a character signifying something. Since I used `List` you'll have to reverse at the end if you want it in order.